# Preset tags are missing from Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I want to add a specific tag to my app on the play store, but I couldn't find it from the list of tags provided by Google, but it's available on several other live apps.

Tag name: `Discounts & coupons`

[image]

But it's not available when I search for it!?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

based on an article in https://www.apptweak.com/en/aso-blog/google-play-store-tags-what-how-to-use-them
some of these automatic tags are not even available for developers to choose from in the Google Play Console. We spotted 11 different tags that cannot be selected in the console but that still sometimes appear in the search results or on the app page.